# Showing the regular representation is decomposable/indecomposable for an explicit example.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

a) Show that the regular representation $V=\mathbb{F}_3 G$ of $G$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_3$ is indecomposable.

b) Provide an explicit decomposition of the regular representation into irreducibles over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$.

---

For part a), I have found an explination a more general case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251932/what-thes-contradiction-in-showing-the-regular-representation-is-indecomposable), where part of the proof claims that if $\mathbb{F}_3 G=M_1\oplus M_2$ is decomposable, then each $M_i$ contains the trivial subrepresentation. How do we know that each $M_i$ contains the trivial subrepresentation? Why can't they be irreducible?

For part b), I believe the decomposition is $\mathbb{F}_2 G=I\oplus N$, where $I=\{\alpha(g_1+g_2+g_3)\mid\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_2\}$ is the trace ideal (trivial representation) and $N=\{\alpha_1g_1+\alpha_2g_2+\alpha_3g_3\mid\alpha_i\in\mathbb{F}_2,\sum_i\alpha_i=0\}$ is the augmentation ideal. If we try the analogous decomposition for part a) as in part b) (i.e., $\mathbb{F}_3 G=$ trace ideal $\oplus$ augmentation ideal), I see that these two ideals have nontrivial intersection (since $|G|=3$ divides the characteristice of $\mathbb{F}_3$), so this is not correct. In particular, the trace ideal is a submodule of the augmentation ideal. However, it seems to me that the augmentation ideal is $G$-stable (hence irreducible) regardless of whether the $|G|$ divides the characteristic. Where is my logic going wrong in this seeming contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\F}{\mathbb F_3}\DeclareMathOperator{\kk}{\mathbb k}$
Let $x$ be a generator of $C_3$. I claim there is an $\F$-algebra isomorphism $\F[t]/(t^3) \longrightarrow \F[C_3]$.
Indeed, consider the map $t\longmapsto x-1$. Since $\F$ has characteristic $3$, we compute directly that $(x-1)^3 = x^3-1= 0$ so this map is indeed well defined. Since $t+1$ maps to $x$, we see this map is surjective, and by counting dimensions we see it is injective.

One now considers the action of $t$ on $\F[t]/(t^3)$ on the basis $\{1,t,t^2\}$. The matrix you get is the usual $3\times 3$ nilpotent Jordan block, which makes this action indecomposable: a direct sum decomposition would mean that this block is nilpotent of order less than three.

For the second part you are right: that is the correct decomposition, but in the modular case it is *not* a direct sum decomposition. In particular, this copy of the trivial representation has no complement in the group algebra, as you noted.

But when $|G|$ and $\mathrm{char}\kk$ are coprime it is a direct sum decomposition, so this works for $G=C_3$ and $\kk=\mathbb F_2$. More precisely, you can consider the basis given by $e_1 = 1+t+t^2$, $e_2 = 1 + t^2$ and $e_3 = t + t^2$ and the subspaces $V = \langle e_1\rangle$ and $W = \langle e_2,e_3\rangle$. You can check directly that $te_2 = e_2 + e_3$ and that $te_3 = e_2$. Thus, the matrix of for this subrepresentation is
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
while $V$ is just the trivial representation. In particular, you can see directly that since $\chi_A(t) =  t^2+t+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb F_2$, the two dimensional subspace $W$ has no one dimensional subrepresentations, and thus it is irreducible. Of course $C_3$ is Abelian, but since $\mathbb F_2$ is not algebraically closed some irreducibles do not have dimension one!

*Add*. Let $G$ have order divisible by $p$ and $\kk$ have characteristic $p$. In $\kk[G]$, consider the sub-representation
$V$ given by the kernel of the algebra map $\varepsilon : \kk[G] \longrightarrow \kk$ such that $\varepsilon(g)=1$ for all $g\in G$. Clearly $V$ is a proper submodule of codimension $1$. Let $\eta = \sum_{g\in G} g$ and notice that $\eta\in V$.

If $W$ is a non-zero submodule of $\kk[G]$ and $w\in W$ is non-zero then $\eta w = \varepsilon(w)\eta$. If this element is zero
then $w\in V$ and $V\cap W\neq 0$, so we may assume that this
element is non-zero. If not, then since $\eta\in V$, we see that this
element is both in $W$ and in $V$, so $W\cap V\neq 0$ in any case. Thus, no pair of non-trivial submodules in $\kk[G]$ have trivial intersection.

Moreover, we have proved that if $W$ is any submodule such that $W\subsetneq V$, then $W$ must contain the trivial representation spanned by $\eta$. Indeed, if $W\subseteq V$ then picking $w\in W\smallsetminus V$ the element $\eta w = \varepsilon(w)\eta\neq 0$ is in $W$.

Comment: I see how this solves part a), but could you additionally offer any insight as to why any submodules would contain the trivial representation? Also, just to clarify, you are saying that the decomposition for part b) works in _every_ case where $|G|$ and $\mathrm{char}\mathbb{k}$ are coprime?

Comment: @J-anon Yes, the decomposition you suggest in your post *always* works in the non-modular case. I am not sure what they are getting at in the post you link to. What is true is that the augmentation ideal of elements in the group algebra whose coefficients add to zero is a submodule that intersects every other non-trivial submodule in the modular case, so it is not possible to have direct sum decompositions into submodules.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does answer all my questions since I just realized I had a misunderstanding thinking $G$-stable $\iff$ irreducible. (I will upvote it when I have 15 rep).